# F# Create 2D Array

Tags: f#

Hi I am wanting to create in F# a 2D array of size 1000x1000, with the value in the array at any position to be initialized as the same vaue of its index using the 2DArray class.

i.e. position [1,1] would have value (1,1).

I have looked at the syntaxt of Array2D.create, but am not sure how to use it properly...

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [Array2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353794.aspx).init to pass a function to specify the initial value of each.

```
let a = Array2D.init 3 3 (fun x y -> (x,y))
printfn "%A" a
```