# F# Initialize 2D string array

Tags: f#

So, I've got a simple structure that just includes a multidimensional array of strings, which looks like so

```
type Structure = 
     struct
      val mutable SubText: string[][]
     end
```

In another function we have something like this:

```
let mutable Struct : Structure = new Structure()

let stringArray = [| "string1"; "string2"; "string3" |]
Struct.SubText.[0] <- stringArray
```

But whenever the program reaches this part we get a NullReferenceException

I'm wondering how I can fix this, thank you.
I did see another question asking nearly the same thing, but that was to do with 2d int arrays, NOT strings

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# Create 2D Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335901/f-create-2d-array)

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa this is no duplicate. The answer for that question doesn't seem to work for string arrays, only for integers.

Comment: @John - init will work just fine for strings.  However the difference here is you have `string [][]` whilst he had `string [,]`

Comment: Yes, an array-of-arrays is not the same thing as a 2D array, at least in .NET terms. It's a 1D array that has another 1D array in each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the first item of the outer array but at this point your array of arrays is still null ; hence the exception.

I don't really understand where you're going with all those mutable and arrays so just a quick workaround to fix the code :

```
let mutable Struct = Structure ()

let stringArray = [| "string1"; "string2"; "string3" |]
Struct.SubText <- [| stringArray |]
```

I just set the whole outer array to an array containing yours you could also do a 2-step process for example

```
let mutable Struct = Structure ()

let stringArray = [| "string1"; "string2"; "string3" |]
Struct.SubText <- Array.zeroCreate 5
// now SubText.[0] exists
Struct.SubText.[0] <- stringArray

// > Struct.SubText;;
// val it : string [] [] = [|[|"string1"; "string2"; "string3"|]; null; null; null; null|]
```

Answer (score 1):

When an instance of `Struct` is constructed by the default no-argument `struct` constructor the structure field `SubText` representing the jugged array of `string` stays uninitialized, so the indexer `Struct.SubText.[0]` gets applied to `null` value, that's why the exception has been thrown.

You may easily fix this by adding to the default no-arg `struct` constructor some extra explicit constructor(s) that initialize `SubText` upon instance construction:

```
type Structure = 
    struct
        val mutable SubText: string[][]
    end
    new(size) = {SubText = Array.zeroCreate size} // to array of given number of string arrays
    new(_) = {SubText = [|[||]|]} // to array of single empty string array
```

Now you may use such constructors as below, the field `SubText` gets initialized upon instance construction and indexer can be used OK:

```
let Struct = new Structure(2) // or just let Struct = new Structure(())
let stringArray = [| "string1"; "string2"; "string3" |]
Struct.SubText.[0] <- stringArray
//Checking out in FSI:
//>Struct.SubText.[0];;
//val it : string [] = [|"string1"; "string2"; "string3"|]
```

As `SubText` is chosen to be `mutable` it can be any time changed to another jugged array of any number of subarrays, not necessarily of initial `size`.